# Jest test execution shows UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning despite the test is working well

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I will try to describe the problem with the minimal reproduction code.

So I have a function with a dependency like this one:

```js
import "./styles.css";

function thatRecivesInjectedDependency(aDependency) {
  aDependency
    .doSomethingAsync()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("it happened");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
}

export default thatRecivesInjectedDependency;
```

And I want to test it with a test double like this:

```js
import sut from ".";

test("should throw an error if the the assets load went wrong", async () => {
  const fakeDependency = {
    doSomethingAsync: jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(new Error("ERROR!")))
  };

  sut(fakeDependency);

  await expect(fakeDependency.doSomethingAsync).rejects.toThrowError(
    new Error("ERROR!")
  );
});
```

For some reason, is the only way I found to make the test work, it's not giving me false positive results, you can check it by changing the error text in the `mockImplementation` or in the `toThrowError` so it will fail, but still is showing up:

```
(node:46044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERROR!
(node:46044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 114)
```

Any clue that what it's happening and how can I resolve it? Did something wrong?

Comment: Is sut the same as thatRecivesInjectedDependency? It looks like that but there should be no guesswork, please, clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a no-op:

```
.catch((error) => {
  throw error;
});
```

`catch` can be perceived by a developer as handled error but this one just rethrows it. If the intention is to allow a caller to handle the error, it can be omitted. If the intention is to suppress the error, it can be changed to `catch(() => {})` but this may lead to other mistakes, as a caller cannot determine if there was an error while this may be important.

`thatRecivesInjectedDependency` doesn't return a promise and there's loose promise chain. A caller is unable to chain it and wait for `thatRecivesInjectedDependency` to finish. That `catch` doesn't really handle errors makes it impossible to handle them in a caller.

It should be:

```
  return aDependency
    .doSomethingAsync()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("it happened");
    });
```

The test doesn't chain the result, this will result in unhandled rejection. Instead it tests itself because it asserts that mocked function rejects; this is already known because this is exactly that was written several lines above.

The coverage can be increased by asserting `console.log`.

It should be:

```
  jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  await expect(sut(fakeDependency)).rejects.toThrowError("ERROR!");
  expect(console.log).not.toBeCalled();
```

Notice that `toThrowError(new Error("ERROR!"))` is excessive because it checks either error constructor or message but not both.